# Access dataframes in rpy2.robjects.methods.RS4

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am trying to import *.rds files in Python.

```
import rpy2
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

pandas2ri.activate()
readRDS = robjects.r['readRDS']
 
temp_data = readRDS('filename.rds')
```

The resulting `temp_data` is of type `rpy2.robjects.methods.RS4`.

```
type(temp_data)
Out[4]: rpy2.robjects.methods.RS4
```

I know that the RDS file should contain dataframes. How can I access the dataframes in `temp_data`?

***Update***
I came across these documentation pages but they didn't help me: https://rpy.sourceforge.io/rpy2/doc-dev/html/_modules/rpy2/robjects/methods.html and https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/generated_rst/s4class.html

Comment: Those documentation pages are for rather old rpy2 releases. Check here: https://rpy2.github.io/doc.html

Answer (score 0):

> I know that the RDS file should contain dataframes. How can I access the dataframes in temp_data?

The RDS may contain data frames as nested elements, but what you observe indicates that the outermost object is an RS4 object. There is documentation about such objects here: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.4.x/html/robjects_oop.html#s4-objects