# Converting *.rds into *.csv file

Tags: r, csv, matrix

I am trying to convert an *.rds file into a *.csv file. First, I am importing the file via `data <- readRDS(file.rds)` and next I am trying to write the CSV file via `write.csv(data,file="file.csv")`.
However, this yields the following error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘structure("dgCMatrix", package = "Matrix")’ to a data.frame
```

How can I turn the *.rds file into a *.csv file?

[image]

Comment: Is your matrix actually sparse, or just represented as sparse?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am not sure to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Sparse matrice often cannot be converted directly into a dataframe.

This answer might be very resource intensive, but it might work by converting the sparse matrix to a normal matrix first and then saving it to a csv.
Try this:

```r
write.csv(as.matrix(data),file="file.csv")
```

This solution is not efficient and might crash R, so save your work prior.

As a general comment, this csv-file will be huge, so it might be more helpful to use more efficient data storage like a database engine.

Comment: I would like to use the data in Python's NumPy/Pandas afterwards so any file format compatible with those two will be fine. I'll try your solution. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `feather`is an option?

Comment: `write_feather(as.matrix(data),"file.feather")` but that returns `Error: 'x' must be a data frame`.

Comment: you could try to read the `.rds`-file directly in python. https://github.com/ofajardo/pyreadr I never used it with matrices before, so I am not sure if it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried that as well. It worked with other RDS files but not with this specific one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70770051/access-dataframes-in-rpy2-robjects-methods-rs4